# Multi row inserts and duplicate key for primary key

Tags: mysql

In mysql, I am currently having an insert statement as below (uid is the primary key)

```
INSERT INTO test ( uid, datetime, precip, sds ) VALUES (?,?,?,?) on duplicate key update uid = "<uid>";
```

Now, I need to perform Multi-row inserts in mysql. I need to check if uid is already existing, update else insert. Since uid is a primary key, each new row contains a new uid. Please let me know if below syntax is right ?

```
INSERT INTO test ( uid, datetime, precip, sds ) VALUES (?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?) on duplicate key update uid = values(<uid for first record>), uid = values(<uid for second record>), uid = values(<uid for third record>), uid = values(<uid for fourth record>);
```

Comment: Could you please provide keys which you have in you test table?

Comment: Primary key in test table is `uid` and that is the only key in the table with no foreign keys. 
So, whenever same uid is seen, all  columns needs to be updated, else insert

Comment: But you can't use this key in `on duplicate key` clause...
This clause works in another way... If you have `duplicate key` case you can change value of `datetime` or some another field of an already existing record in db, but you can't change the value which you're trying to insert into table. Moreover `uid` is primary and unique key and if you have duplicates here it means you have huge problems in your system design...

Comment: The scenario is - we are using orchestration mechanisms like docker swarm and kubernetes, when a worker actually goes down while processing a record (after insertion to DB and commit but messaging Q offset is not yet committed), the other worker when it starts it can pick the same record. So, in that case there has to be be an upsert.

Comment: @ArunShankar The `uid` is a primary key, but is it an `AUTO_INCREMENT column? If it is not, why is that the case? Why do you specify the primary key for the new entry in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, there's two interpretations:

## First interpretation

You want to create a new row with an alternate UID if the main UID already exist in database.

This looks like the right interpretation as you wrote "each new row contains a new uid". But this does not looks natural at all.

For this, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is not the right tool, as it would `update` the existing raw, as indicated by its name, not create a new one.

So to implement this you may just `insert` normally, check if the insertion succeeded, if it failed due to a duplicate uid, insert with the alterantive uid. Not sure what you want to do if it conflicts again, run this in a loop? Looks the wrong way.

## Second interpretation

You want to update if a row with the same uid exists, else insert a new. In other words, you want to insert a new row but just update the existing one if it exists.

This looks like the right interpretation as you wrote "I need to check if uid is already existing, update else insert" and as you're trying with "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE". Also it looks way more natural.

To implement this, you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to `update` the existing row with new values (but do not touch the `uid`) as:

```
INSERT INTO test ( uid, datetime, precip, sds )
VALUES (?,?,?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    datetime = VALUES(datetime),
    precip = VALUES(precip),
    sds = VALUES(sds)
```

And the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement does not change when you have multiple values.

It reads "If the row exists, update the datetime, precip, and sds".